# order by on a django paginator page object

Tags: django

How can I run an order_by on myFinalData? I need to do it after pagination or the pages sort don't make sense

```
myData = Data.objects.all()   
paginator = Paginator(myData, int(limit))
myFinalData = paginator.page(int(page))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to sort just the current page! I would use the normal python sort method, something like that:

```
myData = Data.objects.all()   
paginator = Paginator(myData, int(limit))
page = paginator.page(int(page)) 
final_data = sorted(page.object_list, key=lambda k: k['name'])
```

To sort using an specify key, just  change the lambda!

Some reference: http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Comment: Great thanks how can I sort on a specific field and direction?

Comment: You can use `operator.itemgetter` to sort on a field name. `sorted` takes a reverse argument which you can set to change the order. For example `sorted(page.object_list, key=operator.itemgetter('field_name'), reverse=True)`.